# Spring, Maven : Maven tests failing with 2 transaction managers

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing, testing

I have written a few test cases for our Spring-MVC based project. As the project is huge, we are using 2 Data-sources and 2 Transaction managers, both talking to the same Database using HikariPool.
When using the webapp, if I save an object with 1st data source and retrieve it with 2nd data source, it's working fine, but not when I am running `mvn test`.

Any ideas?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml", "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml"})
@Ignore
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class TestingController {


//All autowired dependencies

}
```

DAO layer where code is failing :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class GroupNotesDAOImpl implements GroupNotesDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_origin")
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_extended")
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory_extended;


    @Override
    public GroupNotes getGroupNoteByIdExtended(int id){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory_extended.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("Id of note is "+id);
        // Getting null below, even though the object exists, id is non-zero
        return (GroupNotes) session.get(GroupNotes.class, id);
    }

}
```

Inside a browser, everything is working just fine. The extended data source is for long running services.

Save DAO code :

```
  @Override
    public int saveGroupNoteAndReturnId(GroupNotes mnotes, int msectionid) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if(mnotes.getCanvasId()!=0) {
            GroupSection groupSection = (GroupSection) session.get(GroupSection.class, msectionid);
            groupSection.getSectionsnotes().add(mnotes);
            mnotes.setOwnednotes(groupSection);
           int saveId = (Integer) session.save(mnotes);
            session.flush();
            return saveId;
        }else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Test cases :

```
// First test calls the save method
    groupNotes = TestUtils.createGroupNotes("testtag", "testtext", loggedInUser.getId());
        groupNotes.setCanvasId(mcanvasId);
        int noteId = this.groupNotesService.saveGroupNoteAndReturnId(groupNotes, msectionId);
        assert noteId!=0;

The 2nd test calls to retrieve the object for duplicating. As duplication is a long run process, it's executed with extended transaction manager
        int success =this.groupNotesService.duplicateGroupNote(noteId, msectionId, groupId, true,true,4.0,false);
       assert(success!=0);
```

root-context.xml :

```
   <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"  destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.USERNAMEql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="maxLifetime" value="30000" />
        <beans:property name="idleTimeout" value="40000" />
        <beans:property name="connectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <beans:property name="maximumPoolSize" value="6"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="url">jdbc:USERNAMEql://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/DB_NAME</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="user">USERNAME</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="password">PASSWORD</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory_origin"/>
    </beans:bean>




    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory_origin" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ourapp.spring.model"/>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.USERNAMEQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="connection.release_mode">after_statement</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="extended_transactions_data_source" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"  destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.USERNAMEql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="maximumPoolSize" value="3" />
        <beans:property name="maxLifetime" value="30000" />
        <beans:property name="idleTimeout" value="40000" />
        <beans:property name="connectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="url">jdbc:USERNAMEql://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/DB_NAME</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="user">USERNAME</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="password">PASSWORD</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager_extended"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager_extended" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory_extended"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory_extended" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="extended_transactions_data_source" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ourapp.spring.model"/>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.USERNAMEQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">25</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_query_cache">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="connection.release_mode">after_statement</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: You're showing us some code but not the most important... How do you insert the data? What is the unit test content ? How your datasources are set?

Comment: @Mumrah81 : Test cases and save code added at bottom of main post. Thank you. :-)

Comment: How are your datasources and transactions configured?

Comment: @Mumrah81 Datasource configuration added at bottom of main post. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Mumrah81 : I also tried adding a qualifier, but that didn't help.

Comment: If i had to make a guess, i would say that the transactional scope may be different between junit and a webapp. What happen if you @Autowired the transactionManager and force a commit between write and read operation?

Comment: @Mumrah81 : Can u give an example? Thanks.

Comment: @Autowired
@Qualifier("transactionManager")
TransactionManager tm;  then before the read call add tm.commit();